# VS Code Error and Related System Path Question

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, path

I recently got the following error msg in VSCode on my windows machine:
*"The environment variable 'Path' seems to have some paths containing the '"' character. The existence of such a character is known to have caused the Python extension to not load. If the extension fails to load please modify your paths to remove this '"' character."*

When I open up a cmd window and type in echo %path% i get the following:

```
C:\Users\james\anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\james\anaconda3\Scripts;"C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.3\bin";;C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.3\bin
```

I have two questions:

1. How do i correct my path to resolve the error i am getting in VSCode
2. why do i have some related items listed twice? for example one reference to julia is in double quotes and the other reference is not

i havent attempted to change anything because i dont want to break stuff. in general, im not very knowledgeable when it comes to modifying paths / envt variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "The environment variable 'Path' seems to have some paths containing
> the '"'

To resolve this issue, you need to remove the double quotes from your `Path` environment variable.

Open your environment vairables, find and select the `Path` variable, then click on `Edit`.

Find the paths that have double quotes and remove the quotes. In your case, you should remove the quotes from `"C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.3\bin"`. It should be `C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.3\bin` after your changing it.

As for your second question, it's not unusual to have duplicate entries in the `Path` variable.
This can happen if a path is added to the `Path` variable more than once, for example, during software installation.
However, having duplicate entries won't cause any issues. The system will use the first matching path it finds when looking for executables.

Comment: thank you. i corrected the error by modifying my envt variables to be: 
C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps; C:\Users\james\AppData\Local\Programs\Julia-1.9.3\bin

now when i call my path i get the double quotes removed as well as the duplicate reference to julia.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, there's a way to modify PATH with a UI. If you are a beginner, I recommend doing that instead of trying to run any terminal commands that might break stuff.

Here's a [tutorial](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) about adding things to PATH. Follow that but remove the entry that has double quotes.